Disable the Click event but Scrolling should Enable
Can we do this in flutter in the webview that clicking is disabled but scrolling is still enable , can anyone help me with this ??
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: AppColors.appbarColor,
        title: Text('Terms of Service'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {},
        onVerticalDragStart: (details) {},
        onVerticalDragEnd: (details) {},
        child: AbsorbPointer(
          absorbing: true,
          child: WebViewWidget(
            controller: _controller
              ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
              ..setNavigationDelegate(
                NavigationDelegate(
                  onProgress: (int progress) {},
                  onPageStarted: (String url) {},
                  onPageFinished: (String url) {},
                  onHttpError: (HttpResponseError error) {},
                  onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
                  onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
                    if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
                      return NavigationDecision.prevent;
                    }
                    return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                  },
                ),
              ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

I have tried this but both clicking and scrolling disabled

Why do you want to disable clicking?

There is some link in the webview and i dont want user to click on that link

Are you the owner of the website displayed in the webview? If so, you can just disable it.

No I cannot do that
